# SQL Insert into table with 2 non-unique primary keys

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that I need to insert data into.

The table `Sales` has 4 columns

- `CustomerValueType_id` (int)
- `Customer_id` (int)
- `Value` (NVARCHAR)
- `Customer_name` (NVARCHAR)

The `CustomerValueType_id`, `Customer_id` are foreign keys that are not-unique, `CustomerValueType_id` matches to a value type, while `Customer_id` matches to the `Customer_name`.

I need to add additional customer data into the `Value`column but how do I ensure that the data matches  to the correct `CustomerValueType_id` and `Customer_id` and each  customer name has to be repeated in the `Customer_name`

[Sales Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGFW5.png)

Comment: The keys you describe are called foreign keys.  They are the primary keys for their respective tables.  Also, if you are storing the foreign key of the customer, there is no reason to store the customer_name in the sales table, as that is an attribute of the customer table.  You get it when you join the tables together.   The sales table should have its own primary key, typically named 'id'.

Comment: Yes that is true, sorry for the confusion. But lets say  insert data in to Values column, how would I ensure the Value type matches to the  CustomerValueType_id   key?

Comment: You need to explain how customervaluetype_id relates to customer.  The list of tables, and columns would be a helpful update to your question.

Comment: I added a pic of what the table looks like, thanks

Comment: The CustomerValueType table just stores what kind of info the id pertains to

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do denormalization.

> Ideally, in the normalized design, you will just store, parent_ids in
>   the child table. If you want to see parent_name fields, you have to
>   get them based on JOIN conditions.

But, here as you are storing both id, name in the child table, I would suggest you to create composite Foreign key in the child table, so that the combination is always present. Also, make this combination as composite primary key in the parent table.

```sql
-- Parent Table PRIMARY KEY
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerValueType 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerValueType 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerValueType_id, Value);
GO

--Child Table FOREIGN KEY
ALTER TABLE dbo.Sales 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Sales_CustomerValueType 
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerValueType_id,Value) 
REFERENCES  dbo.CustomerValueType(CustomerValueType_id,Value);
GO
```